# Running multiple unit test projects at once in C# and xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I want to split a large unit tests project into multiple smaller projects so developers can only build and run the relevant unit tests to what they are doing when they work locally.

The issue is that I still want to run all the unit tests as if they were the big project in our CI for simplicity, coverage and such.

the following command didn't work for me:

```bash
$ dotnet test path/to/subproject1.csproj test path/to/subproject2.csproj
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
```

same with any glob tricks.
I also tried to create a parent project and reference the sub-projects but it ignores the tests in the subprojects.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't get why devs shouldn't be able to execute just a subset of tests from one single test project? I do that all the time. But alas, in the end, you'll probably want to match the test projects to the projects they have tests for. Now, what CI pipeline is in use here? Microsoft? Github? Answers may depend on that. Haven't touched or looked at ours in a while, but I am sure, we are using some sort of glob job, which may internally make several calls, though.

Comment: We have many code projects and having a single unit tests project for all of them causes the build to take a long time. (we have a single big solution).
We are using google cloudbuild, but as long as I can run this using bash, it doesn't matter what CI pipeline we're using.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `sln` file then include all your test projects into it. As the `dotnet test` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) states:

> The dotnet test command is used to execute unit tests in a given
> solution. The dotnet test command builds the solution and runs a test
> host application for each test project in the solution

I don't have any problem in my CI pipeline for running multiple test projects.